# How do you get rid of "SyntaxError: 'await' outside function"

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, discord, bots

I am trying to make a discord bot change to online status

I have been using pycharm and terminal. I have tried reordering the code multiple different ways, but here is what I have right now

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('Bot is ready.')
await client.run(bot token)
```

I also tried these:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('Bot is ready.')
   await client.run(bot token)
on_ready
```

and

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('Bot is ready.')
await client.run(bot token)
on_ready
```

I got these errors:

:8: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_ready' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

and

SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Please help me get the bot online

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `await` cannot be outside of an `async def` function, the thing your awaiting is not indented enough to be inside the function `on_ready`.

Secondly, you shouldn't try to call `on_ready` manually, once the bot runs, it'll call `on_ready` itself.

Thirdly, **Never put `client.run` inside of `on_ready`!** Instead put it at the end of the file, if you do put it inside of on_ready, it'll never run.

so, this would be the ideal code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

And as for storing your bot token, i would put it inside a database, like the replit or mongoDB database.

Answer (score 0):

the await function is not needed for client.run()
put

```
async def on_ready():
        print("Bot is ready.")
```

and put client.run at the end of the file. In my case, I use a file called config.py in which I have declared the value of token

```
token = "Enter your token here"
```

to import the variable, I did imported config with `import config` and since it's in config file, I entered `client.run(config.token)`

[image]

Answer (score -3):

The print function needs to be intended another 4 spaces to be like:

```
async def on_ready():
        print("Bot is ready.")
```

Try to install asyncio if the problem still occurs